# find string in pandas series python

Tags: python, pandas, series

I cannot figure out how to find a string in a pandas series:

```
mydata = np.array(['ab','ac','ad','ae'])
myserie = pd.Series(mydata) # this is because I don't know how to initialise a series directly ... :(
```

I am looking for the index of the string `ac`.

I have tried `myserie.str.find('ac')` but that returns

```
Out[270]: 
0   -1
1   -1
2   -1
3   -1
dtype: int64
```

which has two problems: I want only the index of the `ac` string  (which out be 1), and well, it doesn't spot it.... what am I doing wrong? what would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for test substring:

```
idx = myserie.index[myserie.str.contains('ac')]
```

If need exact match use `==` or [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
idx = myserie.index[myserie.eq('ac')]
print (idx)
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

For scalar use `next` with `iter` trick for return value also if no match:

```
out = next(iter(idx), 'no match')
print (out)
1
```

Comment: thanks for your help! from s.index[myserie.eq('ac')] I get: AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'eq'

Comment: @Lucile - It was typo, changed.

Comment: so nowwww: print(s.index[myserie.eq('ac')])
                      Int64Index([], dtype='int64')

Comment: I get empty brackets [] not [1] like you in Int64Index([], dtype='int64')

Comment: t'was a typo in my code, it works! cheers! that is insanely complicated though... I would have never figured this out by myself!